# Searching in angular

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular app. I have a search bar. code is as follows:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>


input{
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/MACjo6S.png);
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
```

problem is that search bar is not working. TO make it work I added following code.

public myData:any

```
<form>
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." applyFilter($event)>
    </form>
    

  filter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.myData.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

But still it is not filtering data. How can I make it working?

Comment: Check [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#usage-notes), and you can subscribe to valueChanges (as a bonus in pipe add debounce).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```html
<form>
  <input
     type="text"
     name="search"
     placeholder="Search.."
     [(ngModel)]="filterValue"
     (ngModelChange)="applyFilter($event)"
    >
</form>
```

p.s don't forget to define "filterValue" as a global variable